# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4 and i'm installing a iphone application from xcode to test it, this works fine. I also have a iPhone 3gs that was given by my university to install the application, this is also jailbroken but when i try to install it i get "a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found". How can i fix this? (also i do have a developers account, my university lecturer added me but he hasnt activated the account yet and he takes ages to respond to emails -i need to test it now but not sure why that error appears?). Would appreciate some help on this matter..

Answer (score 0):

I assume the provisioning profile you are running doesn't include the UDID of the device you're trying to run on. This requires logging in to the Provisioning Portal and adding the device, then downloading the new profile and installing it on your device.

Comment: but if i jail broken the device, should it not just work? why do i still get this error .. ? do i need to modify a setting somewhere ..?

Comment: Sorry, I never tried compiling through XCode on a jailbroken device, but if you use it straightforward, it should work anyway. I don't know if there is a workaround to cut through the whole provisioning mess...

Comment: Well i have a jailbroken iphone 4 which i own and i just jailbroke it and was able to use straight away. This iphone i received i'm not sure on its previous configurations but i just jailbroke it and i still get this error. It doesnt make sense :(

Comment: Like I said, jailbreaking doesn't help you skip over all the provisioning headache. You still need to create a profile and install on your device.